# Cannot reinstall Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to remove Homebrew so that I can install it on another account. But somewhere along the line I must have messed up. I followed the uninstall tips in the FAQ, and I think i managed to partially remove it. Now when I try the brew doctor I get:

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

So I asume it is partially uninstalled. But when I run the Homebrew installation script I get the following message:

```
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

So I try the rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup and get:

```
rm: /usr/local/.git/branches: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/config: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/description: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/HEAD: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/post-update.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks/update.sample: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/hooks: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/info/exclude: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/info: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/master: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/logs/refs/remotes: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/logs/refs: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/logs: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/objects/info: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/objects/pack/pack-f61919e44996693539de9ee7986ee3c78a0b7c2a.idx: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/objects/pack/pack-f61919e44996693539de9ee7986ee3c78a0b7c2a.pack: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/objects/pack: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/objects: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/refs/heads: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/refs/remotes/origin: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/refs/remotes: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/refs/tags: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git/refs: Permission denied
rm: /usr/local/.git: Directory not empty
```

Now I'm out of ideas on what to do so I can reinstall it. I'm not that familiar with terminal commands so it might be that I'm missing something simple, but please come with suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`

as then you should have permission. However, `brew cleanup` won't work anyway when the brew command is not there anymore. But maybe it will allow you to reinstall Homebrew after that.

Comment: Thank you very much worked perfectly.